# Recipient specific email subject

Tags: docusignapi

Based on a signer we are trying to create signer/recipient specific email subject dynamically. Please see partial Json specific request. With this, in an email, we are able to view the subject correctly. However when we open the document for signing or view the envelope in docusign(Sent Items), we see the `emailSubject` json value which in this case is "Email Subject". This is because this parameter is not a list but and we have to set this value in the outer request object since it is mandatory.

Is there any way to get around this ?

```
"emailSubject": "Email Subject",
"status": "sent",
"recipients": {
    "signers": [{
        "emailNotification": {
            "emailSubject": "Recipient specific subject",
            "emailBody": "Recipient specific body"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to repro the behavior you describe and unfortunately, I don't believe there's any way around this.

It makes sense that the top-level Email Subject would appear for the Envelope in the "**Sent Items**" folder -- because if there were multiple recipients for an Envelope each with a distinct custom email subject, then there'd be no way to display all of them -- hence, it just always displays the top-level Subject in the Sent Items folder.

What doesn't make sense is for the recipient-specific Subject that you specified in the Create Envelope request to be shown in the email that the recipient receives, but NOT shown in the Envelope itself during the recipient's DocuSign signing session.  This inconsistency seems like a bug to me.

i.e., with the example request that follows, the Subject in the Email and the Subject shown during the recipient's Signing session should both be the same (i.e., should both be the recipient-specific value that's specified by the request).  Perhaps someone with DocuSign can chime in and either explain this behavior, or confirm the existence of this bug.

**"Create Envelope" Request Body:**

```
{
    "emailBlurb":"Test Email Body",
    "emailSubject": "Test Email Subject",
    "status" : "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "inlineTemplates": [
        {
            "sequence" : 1,
            "recipients": {
                "signers" : [{
                    "email": "sallysemail@outlook.com",
                    "name": "Sally Adamson",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "defaultRecipient": "true",
                    "emailNotification": {
                                "emailSubject": "Recipient specific subject",
                                "emailBody": "Recipient specific body"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }],
        "document": {
            "documentId": 1,
            "name": "NDA",
            "transformPdfFields": "true"
        }
    }
  ]
 }
```

**Recipient Email (shows recipient-specific subject):**
  [image: recipient email]

**Recipient Signing Session (shows top-level Subject instead of Recipient-specific subject):**
 [image]

Comment: Thank you Kim for putting up a detailed example.Like you mentioned,hopefully someone from Docusign can explain this behavior.

Comment: I believe this functionality is by design.  Each envelope in DocuSign has one single Email Subject, and this always shows when any recipient views the envelope through the DocuSign Console.  This is to avoid confusion and to help identify envelopes.  Any recipient-specific email subject that is set only goes out in that particular email notification to that particular recipient - the envelope still retains the main Email Subject that it was originally configured with.

Comment: My email subject always says "Please Docusign:". Is this in the resource? I've tried changing it thru the api by setting the email subject, but it still says "Please Docusign".

Comment: Are you setting Envelope Subject via API in the "Create Envelope" API request?